# use xml tree iter method but be aware of end of a given branch

Tags: python, xml

Let us say I have an xml file of with several childs and I want to iterate until the end of one of the branches.

```
<bookstore>
  <classical>This classiccal books</classical>
     <date>2017-05-31</date>
        <schedule>
            <type>Blues</type>
            <region>
                 <name>Alaska</name>
                 <transaction>
                     <transactionNo>455</transactionNo>
        ...
        </schedule>
        <schedule>
        </schedule>
        <anotherTag>
        </anotherTag>
...
```

I want to iterate over the xml tree and be aware every time I enter the branch schedule for the first time and then also be aware when I exit the branch schedule.

How can I do this using the xml tree parser in python?

If I do the search of all descendants I know when I enter it for the first time but not when I exit it?  Could I modify the code below to be aware when I leave the branch schedule?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
tree = ET.parse(xml_data)
for elem in tree.iter():
    print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please upvote if so, and mark accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do [a query](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) to get the elements you want, and then loop through them individually, instead of iterating through everything:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_data = '''
<bookstore>
    <schedule><type>Foo</type></schedule>
    <schedule><type>Bar</type></schedule>
    <schedule><type>Baz</type></schedule>
</bookstore>
'''
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
for schedule in tree.findall("schedule"):
    print schedule.find("type").text
```